# android:layout_marginBottom not leaving space at bottom

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-tabhost, android-framelayout, tabwidget

I have a TabHost activity in my project. When I have the following XML, the tabs are off the screen and they don't show at all.

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activityVerticalMargin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activityHorizontalMargin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activityHorizontalMargin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activityVerticalMargin"
    tools:context=".SomeActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

            <some elements here>

        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

However, if I slightly modify to look like this, the tabs show but they are not at the bottom and it is not how I want it to look.

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activityVerticalMargin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activityHorizontalMargin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activityHorizontalMargin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activityVerticalMargin"
    tools:context=".SomeActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

            <!-- layout_height above was changed to wrap_content -->

            <some elements here>

        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Why is it not working in the first case? Isn't layout_marginBottom supposed to make the height of the layout `match_parent - margin` (which is 50dp in this case)?

Comment: your code would do match_parent - 100dp (50dp of tabweight and 50dp of marginBottom). Match_parent will occupy all the space that is left in a linearlayout. In a relativelayout it will be match_parent - 50dp (50dp of marginbottom)

Comment: So, how should I change this?

Comment: Convert parent LinearLayout to Relativelayout. Frame layout should have parameter align_parenttop = true and the tabwidget should have align_parentBottom = true. Let the rest remain.

Comment: Yep that works. Just curious, there is no way to make this work using a LinearLayout?

Comment: it is just about playing with different types of layouts and margins/padding. There would be other methods also. Unless you need to use a specific feature of linearlayout this should be fine. I have submitted the answer. It would be great if you can mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert parent LinearLayout to Relativelayout. Frame layout should have parameter align_parenttop = true and the tabwidget should have align_parentBottom = true. Let the rest remain.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is one way to do this via `LinearLayout` (we should avoid `RelativeLayout` anyways). We can provide a negative margin to your `TabWidget` element. Here's how your layout will look:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:id="@+id/tabHost"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activityVerticalMargin"
         android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activityHorizontalMargin"
         android:paddingRight="@dimen/activityHorizontalMargin"
         android:paddingTop="@dimen/activityVerticalMargin"
         tools:context=".SomeActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">

            <!-- some elements here -->

        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```